# Grid alternate color

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, grid

I am trying to display a Grid with alternating color each other row. The best would be alternating template all together to be able to change the whole row.

To make sure there is no misunderstanding when i mean grid i mean grid, not datagrid, not gridview, grid as in `<Grid></Grid>`

Right now the only viable solution i have found was to make a grid with the appropriate amount of rows i want and in each rows i put another grid with 1 row and the 3 columns i need and copy pasted for each row by changing the back color. As you can see this is not very clean solution.

So i have looked around and found that the listbox can have the alternate count and on a simple trigger it can change everything and that was perfect until i noticed the highlight CANNOT be disabled. You can change the highlight brush but it override an alternate color so both cannot be used at the same time. Before you asked yes i did use the transparent bush and transparent is NOT really transparent, All it does is that it shows the color underneath the ListBox control which was the beige color of the canvas underneath and the item itself disappear.

Anyone know a way to apply a template of alternating row on a grid. Putting a simple style on the `RowDefinition` would be easy but since you can't really tell the type of element you put in a grid i doubt there is something that can be done as easy as that.

EDIT:
 here my latest change. a little bit "cleaner"
i created 2 style for item control for each color theme like

```
<Style x:Key="PropertyGrid" TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="White">                           
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="AlternatePropertyGrid" TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="#FFEBEBEB">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then i used a stack panel and listed each line

```
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl Style="{StaticResource PropertyGrid}">
        <Label Content="Identifier" Style="{StaticResource PropertyNameLabel}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=cboActions, Path=SelectedItem.UniqueIdentifier}" Style="{StaticResource PropertyValueLabel}"/>
        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource PropertyGridSplitter}"/>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl Style="{StaticResource AlternatePropertyGrid}">
        <Label Content="Source" Style="{StaticResource AlternatePropertyNameLabel}"/>
        <Label Name="lblSource" Style="{StaticResource AlternatePropertyValueLabel}"/>
        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource AlternatePropertyGridSplitter}"/>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl Style="{StaticResource PropertyGrid}">
        <Label Content="Description" Style="{StaticResource PropertyNameLabel}"/>
        <Label Name="lblActionDescription" Style="{StaticResource PropertyValueLabel}"/>
        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource PropertyGridSplitter}"/>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

each item in their respective style they have the grid column preset so style determine the location in the grid of each object within the item control.

It works but still i feel like there is probably a more efficient way to do it. here's a screenshot of what it look like right now, might be more helpful for the visual people to know what i am trying to achieve here.

[image]

Comment: why not extend the control and add DependencyProperties that do this for you?

Comment: Possible but i would still have to create an extended control for each style i am planning on using. But indeed it would make the XAML cleaner.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Repeating the code was fastest solution.

Answer (score 0):

With a Datagrid, you can easily do that :

```
<DataGrid  AlternatingRowBackground="Blue"/>
```

With a grid, no idea :p

Answer (score 0):

For a listbox inside the Grid, we set alternate colors with a some lines of code (code-behind).

```
    private void SetAlternateColor()
    {
        var blueBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        var redBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
        {
            ListBoxItem item = TestListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListBoxItem;
            item.Background = i % 2 == 0 ? blueBrush : redBrush;
        }
    }

    private void TestGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetAlternateColor();
    }
```

Don't know if this is what you are looking for.